# WooCommerce variations drop down not showing until add to cart is pressed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I need help with a website I have built.

http://www.fuzzybrush.com

Basically, if you go to any product https://fuzzybrush.com/product/stay-fresh-pack-of-10-extra-strong/ for example, the quantity and add to cart shows. However, this is a variable product and should show the variation dropdowns.

The variations all have prices and should show before the add to cart. When you click add to cart you get an error advising "Please choose product options…" and the variation dropdown now appears.

Any idea why the dropdown doesn't appear BEFORE the add to cart? I have ruled out the theme, plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this code in css section

```
 .orderby, .woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations td select {
     display:block!important;
 }
```